# What is harmonic and fundamental bands in IR spectroscopy?

Tags: spectroscopy, raman-spectroscopy

What is harmonic and fundamental bands in IR spectroscopy?

I'm trying to find exact definitions.

I guess that fundamental is $1\leftarrow 0$ transition (the most intense and energetic) and harmonic is other transitions like $2\leftarrow 0$ or $2\leftarrow 1$ (less intense and less energetic).

Is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost correct. Harmonics are the multiples of the base frequency. In harmonic oscillator both $1\leftarrow 0$ and $2\leftarrow 1$ transitions have the same frequency $\omega$, whereas the frequency of $2\leftarrow 0$ transition is $2\omega$.